# How to mutate a column of a grouped dataframe using pandas in a more readable way?

Tags: pandas

I would like to transform this table:

```
    key1    key2    data1
0   a       one     1
1   a       two     2
2   b       one     3
3   b       two     4
4   a       one     5
```

into this table:

```
    key1    key2    data1   sum
0   a       one     1       6
1   a       two     2       2
2   b       one     3       3
3   b       two     4       4
4   a       one     5       6
```

using pandas and this dataframe:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({
    'key1': ['a','a','b','b','a'],
    'key2': ['one','two','one','two','one'],
    'data1': [1,2,3,4,5]
}) #.
```

But, without having to write something like this:

```
df.set_index(['key1','key2']).join(df.groupby(['key1','key2'])['data1'].sum().to_frame().rename(columns = {'data1':'sum'}), on = ['key1','key2']).reset_index() #.
```

How can I produce the desired result in a more readable way?

Comment: You want to use `groupby().transform('sum')` to broadcast the result back to every row of the original DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['sum'] = df.groupby(['key1','key2'])['data1'].transform('sum')
df
```

Or to create a copy of the dataframe, you can use `assign`:

```
df.assign(sum=df.groupby(['key1','key2'])['data1'].transform('sum'))
```

Output:

```
  key1 key2  data1  sum
0    a  one      1    6
1    a  two      2    2
2    b  one      3    3
3    b  two      4    4
4    a  one      5    6
```